# Need to send a 410 response code before www redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404, no-www

Currently, a bunch of fake pages from a client's website are showing up in Google's search result. All the URLs exist in the /bin/ directory. In order to clear them from the search results as quickly as possible, I'm trying to send a 410 from any URL in that directory.

The issue: Currently, the htaccess file is first redirecting to the www version and then sending a 404 response. (EXAMPLE: http://example.com redirects to http://www.example.com, which sends a 404) I would like to send the 410 response directly from any version of the URL.

My htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^bin/?$ - [G,NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
# [NC] is a case-insensitive match
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

I thought this line would cause any URL in the /bin/ directory (example.com/bin/example) to send a 410, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything:

```
RewriteRule ^bin/?$ - [G,NC]
```

Any help is much appreciated.
Thank you

EDITED FOR CLARITY

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what you ask. I cannot see any rules in the code above that might try to implement what you describe here. So all we can give is a general hint: if you want to handle those requests you want to reply to with a 404 _before_ you redirect to the `www` host name, then place the rules _before_ those implementing that redirection.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The line in question:

**RewriteRule ^bin/?$ - [G,NC]** I thought this would send a 410 response code from any url in the /bin/ directory (example.com/bin/test). However, it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Comment: In that case just remove the trailing `$` in the pattern. With it only the exact request to the "folder" is rejected, without that control character all requests to URLs _starting_ with `bin/...` will match.

Comment: Thank you arkascha! I'll give that a try, but it looks like it was just a silly mistake :)